# Parsing .csv into clauses in Haskell

Tags: haskell, csv

I am trying to convert a .csv of

```
femin,femin,1,f,woman,women,
aqu,aqu,1,f,water,waters,
..
```

into a file of .pl like

```
noun(femin,femin,1,f,trans(woman,women)).
noun(aqu,aqu,1,f,trans(water,waters)).
..
```

here is my current source code:

```
-- get from "femin, femin, 1, f, woman, women" to noun(femin, femin, 1, f ,trans(woman,women)). 
import qualified Data.Attoparsec as P


data NounClause = NounClause
    {
        nom :: String,
        gen :: String,
        declension :: String,
        gender :: String,
        sgtrans :: String,
        pltrans :: String
    } deriving Show 

parseNounClause :: P.Parser NounClause

parseNounClause = do 
    nom <- String
    char ","
    gen <- String
    char ","
    declension <- String
    char ","
    gender <- String
    char ","
    sgtrans <- String
    char ","
    pltrans <- String
    return $ NounClause nom gen declension gender sgtrans pltrans
```

However, this does not seem to be working. Why is this so?

Also, how can I apply this parser to each line? Here also is my function that takes the parsed data and returns a string.

```
c = ","
convert :: NounClause -> String
convert NounClause = "noun(" ++ nom ++ c ++ gen ++ c ++ declension ++ c ++ gender ++ "trans(" ++ sgtrans ++ c ++ pltrans ++ "))."
```

I very much thank anyone who helps me on this project; their contribution is most valuable to me.

Comment: By the way, I recommend checking out [Cassava](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Csv.html) or some other CSV parsing library if you are parsing CSV documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the String parser, it tries to consume as much input as possible. This includes the commas in your file.
So you construct a parser that reads everything except for commas.

```
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Text as P
import Data.Text(unpack)

entry = fmap unpack (P.takeWhile (/=','))
```

unpack is used to convert the parsed info of type `Text` into a String.

Then you need an additional parser that reads a comma.

```
separator = P.char ','
```

Then we combine this to parse a `NounClause`

```
parseNounClause :: P.Parser NounClause
parseNounClause = do 
    nom <- entry
    separator -- don't need the comma so no need to keep it.
    gen <- entry
    separator
    declension <- entry
    separator
    gender <- entry 
    separator
    sgtrans <- entry
    separator
    pltrans <- entry
    separator
    return $ NounClause nom gen declension gender sgtrans pltrans
```

So now you want to read multiple lines. This is the same as the comma but now with a newline symbol.
We parse an entry and a newline symbol alternating. To compensate for n lines but only n-1 newline symbols we make a distinction for the first line. The `many'` combinator allows us to parse zero or more lines of the same format.

```
multiLines = do x <- parseNounClause
                xs <- many' (do P.endOfLine
                                clause <- parseNounClause
                                return clause
                           )
                return (x:xs)
```

So now wee need to parse this. This is done by the following main Function. For which we need another import, to read the Fileinfo as of type `Text`

```
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T(readFile)

main :: IO ()
main = do fileContents <- T.readFile "input.txt"
          let result = P.parseOnly multiLines fileContents
          case result of (Left s)   -> putStrLn s
                         (Right rs) -> sequence_ (map (putStrLn . show) rs)
```

The parse result will get us either an error message or all `NounClause`s in a list. I use `sequence_ (map (putStrLn .show)` to print it.

You have the function show, which can convert your data type into a `String` because you added the `deriving Show` at the end of the definition if you want to use your own `String` representation instantiate the type class yourself (instead of your `convert` function) like:

```
instance Show NounClause where
    show n = ...
```

Comment: Also you already have a function that returns a string. It is called  `show` ans instatiated by the `deriving Show` If you would like to have your own format you should instantiate your own instance of the Typeclass Show and not derive it.

Comment: Thank you very much MoFu. However, I do not understand what you mean in your comment.

Comment: @user2850249 you have your function convert which transforms your data structure in a string. You also have added `deriving Show` behind the definition of the data type. Because of this dering you have a function `show :: NounClause -> String`, which most people will use to convert something into a String. If you want a custom show you better instantiate your own Show typeclass http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html )